# Accessing VM on host machine through IP address

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, centos, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to set up a CentOS VM with VMware Fusion and get access to it through the host.

I was following a tutorial online for this as this is my first time doing this. When I try to access the IP of the VM through Chrome on the host, I should be seeing the Apache CentOS home page, but I get the "Oops, Chrome couldn't connect to the IP".

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: I am able to ping the VM from the host, but when I try running telnet:

> **`telnet`*(VM IP address)***
>   `Trying`*(VM IP address)*`...`
>   `telnet: connect to address`*(VM IP address)*`: Connection refused`
>   `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

I have gone ahead and made sure the firewall on the vm is disabled. I also changed the network settings for the vm in vmware fusion to autodetect under bridged networking. Its set to appear as an additional computer on the same physical network connection as my computer.

Comment: What happens if you do `telnet (vmname) 80`?

Comment: Trying (vm ip address)... telnet: connect to address (vm ip address): Connection refused telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: You should had told what kinda configuration you're using, I mean Are you using mode bridge for the virtual machine? I'm talking about the network configuration for the vm. It's important that your vm be in the same range of LAN IP as you host machine. For example: host -> 10.0.0.2 vm -> 10.0.03 Well, I guess you understood. Regards.

Comment: what mode is vmware running in? bridged, NAT, or what? Bridged mode is usually what you want. check [here](http://jesin.tk/vmware-bridged-networking/) for how to do that. Then give us your IP addresses of the VM and host machine with subnet mask for each. Also in your VM you want to make sure that you have your firewalls either off or configured to allow traffic to pass through to the web page

Comment: I tried the bridged networking, there are a couple options, right now I have it set to autodetect. The ips do seem to be in the same range, the vm's 192.168.1.71 and the host machines is 192.168.1.64